# Not clearing the input (text) field value after Add / Remove Multiple Input Fields Dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular10, dynamic-forms

I am able to dynamically Add or Remove multiple input fields, But the issue is once I have added items and enter some values in the input fields and remove it using delete button, values are not getting cleared, i have tried to empty my array for that index as well but it is not working. Any suggestions please?

I appreciate your help!

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="row">
   <div>
    <button mat-raised-button (click)="test()">Add </button>
   </div>
    <div *ngFor="let value of fieldArray; let i = index">
        <mat-form-field >          
          <input matInput value="{{getDataValue(i)}}" (focusout)="onFocusOut($event)"  name ="test">
          
        </mat-form-field>
        <button mat-raised-button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm "  (click)="remove(i)">Delete</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

code in  my .ts file:

fieldArray: Array = [];

```
 remove(i: number) {
    
    this.fieldArray.splice(i,1);
    
  }

test(){        
        this.fieldArray.push(this.fieldArray.length);       
   }
```

Comment: can you please provide getDataValue() functiona for more clarity

Comment: getDataValue(index) {
    if(this._value.size > 0){            
      return this._value.get("test_" + index);
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  }

Answer (score 0):

With TrackBy, Angular is able to detect which items are deleted or added to an array, using a unique identifier. So, only the items added or removed have to be updated in the DOM.

Like below code for view:

```
<div *ngFor="let value of fieldArray; let i = index; trackBy: trackByFn">
```

Below code for .ts file:

```
trackByFn(index, item) {
    return index; // or item.id
}
```